# How to create a horizontal tree using braces

Tags: trees, forest

I want to create a horizontal tree-like structure using braces, as in:

[horizontal tree http://bto.io/files/horizontal_tree.jpg](http://bto.io/files/horizontal_tree.jpg)

Please forgive my lack of creativity.

I tried using an equation, for example

```
\begin{equation*}
\text{Animals}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
& \text{Cats} &
\\
& \text{Dogs}
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation*}
```

except this is difficult to read and I cannot get the third layer.

I suspect the `forest` package would work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.